# PlasticSCM - why do I have to apply Label after creating it

Tags: label, plasticscm

In PlasticSCM, when I want to label a changeset, I have to create a label then apply it. What does applying the label do? what happens if I do not apply the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually creating the label is enough. The create/apply pair is a leftover from the old days when we applied labels to individual revisions (before Plastic 4.0).

Now labels are applied to labels so it is just a matter of creating the label, that's all (it has been this way for years already). We will clean up the places where the create/apply still exists